# Linq union not able to concat more than 2 resultset. Works only concatenating till 2 result set

Tags: c#, linq

In my program I am returning 3 resultset:

1)resultImportResponse
2)resultUploadRespsone
3)resultAttach

I am checking that if all of them are not null I want to concate them into one resultset.

So I have declare`var result = (dynamic)null;`

It works fine till I combine any of 2 result set.

But say if I do  `result = resultImportResponse.Union(resultAttach); //this works fine`

but say whatever result I got if I try to append third result set it gives error

```
result = resultImportResponse.Union(resultAttach); 
result = result.Union(resultUploadResponse);  //this gives error
```

See sample below

```
public JsonResult GetImportExportAttachmentLog(int doccode)
{

    List<RequestDetail> objImportExportLogs = null;

    objExportLogs = objProxyDownloadManager.GetDownloadRequestDetail(objRequestDetail);

    List<UploadRequest> objImportLogs = null;

    objImportLogs = objProxyUploadManager.GetUploadRequestDetail(objUploadRequestDetail);

    var resultImportResponse = (from i in objExportLogs
                                orderby i.RequestTime descending
                                select new
                                {

                                    Status = i.DownloadStatus.ToString(),
                                    ErrorMessage = i.ErrorLogDescription,
                                    FileId = i.FileId,
                                    FileUri = i.FileUri,
                                    FileName = i.FileName,
                                    IsDownload = i.DownloadStatus.ToString().TrimEnd() == "Complete" ? true : false
                                });

    var resultUploadResponse = (from i in objImportLogs
                                orderby i.RequestStartTime descending
                                select new
                                {
                                    Status = i.UploadStatus.ToString(),
                                    ErrorMessage = i.ErrorLogDescription,
                                    FileId = i.FileId,
                                    FileUri = i.FileUri,
                                    FileName = i.FileName,
                                    IsUpload = i.UploadStatus.ToString().TrimEnd() == "Complete" ? true : false
                                });

    //For Attachment,Start Here
    List<RequestDetail> objAttachImportExportLogs = null;
    objAttachLogs = objProxyDownloadManager.GetDownloadRequestDetail(objAttachRequestDetail);

    var resultAttach = (from i in objAttachImportExportLogs
                        orderby i.RequestTime descending
                        select new
                        {
                            Status = i.DownloadStatus.ToString(),
                            ErrorMessage = i.ErrorLogDescription,
                            FileId = i.FileId,
                            FileUri = i.FileUri,
                            FileName = i.FileName,
                            IsDownload = i.DownloadStatus.ToString().TrimEnd() == "Complete" ? true : false
                        });
    //For Attachment,Ends Here

    var result = (dynamic)null;


    if ((!Equals(resultImportResponse, null) && !Equals(resultAttach, null) && !Equals(resultUploadResponse, null)) && (resultImportResponse.Count() > 0 && resultAttach.Count() > 0 && resultUploadResponse.Count() > 0))
    {
        result = resultImportResponse.Union(resultAttach);
        // result = result.Union(resultUploadResponse);
        result = Enumerable.Union(result, resultUploadResponse);
    }
    else if (!Equals(resultImportResponse, null) && resultImportResponse.Count() > 0)
    {
        result = resultResponse;
    }
    else if (!Equals(resultAttach, null) && resultAttach.Count() > 0)
    {
        result = resultAttach;
    }
    else if (!Equals(resultUploadResponse, null) && resultUploadResponse.Count() > 0)
    {
        result = resultUploadResponse;
    }
    return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: have you looked at `Enumerable.Join()` method perhaps this is what you really need

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the two you try to union on to start with are the same object (or at least they are both anonymous types with fields `Status, ErrorMessage, FileId, FileUri, FileName, IsDownload`) - I can't test this at the moment, so I may be wrong, but I'm reasonably sure it's the case. Your `resultUploadResponse` on the other hand is of a different type (well contains an `IsUpload` field instead of an `IsDownload` field.)

To fix it, you need all the `IEnumerable`s to be of the same class.. so create some class, eg:

```
public class Result {
    public string Status;
    public string ErrorMessage;
    public string FileId; //Maybe int? can't tell from your code
    public string FileUri;
    public string FileName;
    public bool IsDownload;
    public bool IsUpload;
}
```

And then your LINQ should be, eg:

```
var resultUploadResponse = (from i in objImportLogs
                            orderby i.RequestStartTime descending
                            select new Result
                            {
                                Status = i.UploadStatus.ToString(),
                                ErrorMessage = i.ErrorLogDescription,
                                FileId = i.FileId,
                                FileUri = i.FileUri,
                                FileName = i.FileName,
                                IsUpload = i.UploadStatus.ToString().TrimEnd() == "Complete";
                            });
```

And change that similarly on all of them :).

Also, whilst in this case, `Union` and `Concat` LINQ statements will do the same thing, conceptually, you're doing a `Concat`, so maybe you should use that function instead :).

### Alternatively:

As you want to use `dynamic`s, you can do the same with dynamics, but the individual elements need to be dynamic, not the `result` variable, so if you want to avoid strongly typing a `Result` class, you can do:

```
var resultUploadResponse = (from i in objImportLogs
                            orderby i.RequestStartTime descending
                            select (dynamic) new
                            {
                                Status = i.UploadStatus.ToString(),
                                ErrorMessage = i.ErrorLogDescription,
                                FileId = i.FileId,
                                FileUri = i.FileUri,
                                FileName = i.FileName,
                                IsUpload = i.UploadStatus.ToString().TrimEnd() == "Complete";
                            });
```

and similarly for the other ones.

Comment: Yes, for a union to work with anonymous types all the properties must be the same.